# Deleting whilst using INNER JOIN sqlplus

Tags: sql, oracle, inner-join, sqlplus

Ive been struggling to work out how I can delete the rows from the RENTALLINE_ID in RENTALLINE_1 and then delete RENTAL_ID from the RENTAL_1. I have the select statement which finds the exact values I want to delete. It finds the records older than 3 years. I am using SQLPlus with command line interface.

```
select rentalline_1.rentalline_ID,
       rentalline_1.tool_store_id,
       rentalline_1.rental_id,
       rentalline_1.qty,
       rental_1.datein
from rental_1
  inner join rentalline_1 on rental_1.rental_id = rentalline_1.rental_id
where MONTHS_BETWEEN (SYSDATE, DATEIN) > (36)
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't test on an oracle database here, but I would expect

```
DELETE rental_1, rentalline_1
from rental_1
  inner join rentalline_1 on rental_1.rental_id = rentalline_1.rental_id
where MONTHS_BETWEEN (SYSDATE, DATEIN) > (36)
```

you could also give it a swing with

```
DELETE from
( SELECT * 
from rental_1
  inner join rentalline_1 on rental_1.rental_id = rentalline_1.rental_id
where MONTHS_BETWEEN (SYSDATE, DATEIN) > (36) )
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I get the error " command not properly ended" on line 1 "DELETE rental_1, rentalline_1". Dont suppose you know why?

Answer (score 1):

Can you add constraints to the database? If you have a foreign key constraint like:

```
ALTER TABLE rentalline_1 ADD CONSTRAINT fk_rental FOREIGN KEY (rental_id) REFERENCES rental_1 (rental_id) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

then deleting the rows in the `rental_1` table will cause the corresponding rows in `rentalline_1` to be deleted automatically.

Comment: Thanks misread this at first but I think this will solve the problem as I can just delete from rental table and miss out using the inner join I think? Thanks

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply but i tried the one below first but i'm sure yours will work too for anyone with a similar problem to me :) Thanks again